# Formatting characters in C, justification

Tags: c, printing, formatting

Hello I want my next output, that would be the letter in this case, to be output 8 spaces after the previous output. This works for the first character, but a printf statement after is not working. It's printing immediately after the first printf statement, and I am trying to get it to be 8. The issue is that when I use '\t', that doesn't help me with my program, b/c I am doing a peg puzzle jump and I need it to be exact. I tried both - and + but it's not working. So I want the "A" to be printed eight spaces to the right of variable pa. Does anybody know what to use here?

```
for ( row =1 ; row <= 5; row++ ){
        for ( column = 1; column <= row; column++ ) {
            if ( row == 1 ) {
                printf("%+8c", pa);
                printf("%-8");
                printf("A");
            }
```

Comment: `printf("%8c%8c", pa, 'A');` or `9` if you want 8 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a specific amount of spaces, you can do the following

```
printf("%*c", n, ' ');
```

where n is some integer aka the number of spaces you want to print. So in your situation you could try the following in your if statement,

```
printf("%c%*c%c%*c", pa, 8, ' ', 'A', 8, ' ');
```

which will first print `pa`, then 8 spaces, then `A`, then another 8 spaces.